# How to use the http import cookies to create a SimpleCookie Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, cgi, session-cookies

I would like to ask how to use the SimpleCookie() that is the standard for cookie management handling in Python3?

```
    simple_cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie()
    simple_cookie['SESSION'] = session_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first get the imports

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
from http import cookies
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern') # use your current timezone
```

Next,  the Python3 code to initialize the cookie, the datetime from current timezone to GMT, and the domain

```
def convert_datetime_est_to_utc(date_time_dt):
    expires = date_time_dt.replace(tzinfo=eastern).astimezone(pytz.utc)
    return expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT') # GMT/UTC

domain = os.environ['HTTP_HOST'].lower()
domain = domain.replace('www.', '')

now = datetime.now()
date_time_dt = now + timedelta(days=2) # a cookie that lasts for 2 days

simple_cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie()
simple_cookie['SESSION'] = session_val # should be a random string that is distinct for each user of a website
simple_cookie['SESSION']['expires'] = convert_datetime_est_to_utc(date_time_dt)
simple_cookie['SESSION']['path'] = '/'
simple_cookie['SESSION']['comment'] = 'This is the website description'
simple_cookie['SESSION']['domain'] = f""".{domain}"""
simple_cookie['SESSION']['max-age'] = str(60*60*24*2)
simple_cookie['SESSION']['secure'] = True
simple_cookie['SESSION']['samesite'] = 'None'
```

Lastly, output the cookie

```
simple_cookie.output()
```

For example,  to Python3 cgi output unicode text and output the session cookie

```
def enc_print(string='', encoding='utf8'):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(string.encode(encoding) + b'\n') # for unicode output Python cgi

enc_print( simple_cookie.output() )
enc_print("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8;")
enc_print()
enc_print(html)
```

Final note, I generate my session_val using PostgreSQL SELECT uuid_generate_v1() and SELECT uuid_generate_v4() statements, e.g., uuid_session = uuid_v1 + '_' + uuid_v4 and then check in the database that it is distinct,  but you could use use Python3 random also

```
import random

def password(length=11):
  
  #chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()+'
  chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
  pwd = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(length))
  return pwd[:length]

print( password(50) )
```